# How To Consume multiple message per request using Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Using RabbitMQ, I have a producer producing a large quantity (10s of thousands) of messages on a queue.  I would like to make the consumer pull a block of 1000 messages per request from the queue.   We are using the Spring AMQP implementation to get messages but trying to figure out how to achieve pulling more than one per request.   The prefetch doesn't seem to be the right option and batch processing seems to need to be done on the producer side.

What are the options to make a consumer request to get a block of messages to be processed as a group?

Example of our setup

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue")
   void listen(String in) {
      log.info(in);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Batching on the consumer side has has been supported since version 2.2

```java
/**
 * Set to true to present a list of messages based on the {@link #setBatchSize(int)},
 * if the listener supports it. This will coerce {@link #setDeBatchingEnabled(boolean)
 * deBatchingEnabled} to true as well.
 * @param consumerBatchEnabled true to create message batches in the container.
 * @since 2.2
 * @see #setBatchSize(int)
 */
public void setConsumerBatchEnabled(boolean consumerBatchEnabled) {
    this.consumerBatchEnabled = consumerBatchEnabled;
}
```

It is only supported by the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#de-batching

> Starting with version 2.2, the SimpleMessageListenerContainer can be use to create batches on the consumer side (where the producer sent discrete messages).

> Set the container property `consumerBatchEnabled` to enable this feature.

Use `List<String> in` in the method signature.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#receiving-batch

```java
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "batch.1")
public void listen1(List<Thing> in) {
    ...
}

// or

@RabbitListener(queues = "batch.2")
public void listen2(List<Message<Thing>> in) {
    ...
}
```

When using Spring Boot auto configuration for the container factory, set `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.consumer-batch-enabled:true` (and `batch-size`).

You also have to set `batchListener=true`; Boot does not provide that as a property, you can add something like this to set it.

```java
@Component
class FactoryCustomizer {

    FactoryCustomizer(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory) {
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Gary Russel Thank you for the quick response. For the batch response:

We have investigated this and the issue is Consumer Batch Processing requires the Producer to be batching.  In our test, our messages are byte arrays.   Enabling the Consumer Batching causes each message byte array to be turned into a list of bytes on the consumer.   We originally thought this was going to solve our issue but since it's still just parsing a single message into batches it won't work.

Comment: No, No, No, `consumerBatchEnabled` does not require any changes to the producer. It creates batches internally. Read the links. Producer batching and consumer debatching are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Here, my suggestion is that you can produce the message into multiple queues(for eg: 5 queues), then enable consumer for 5 queues. Divide and produce the data to 5 queues so that the consumer will be running 5 consumer threads(for each queue) it will consume the speed 5X faster.

Comment: Thanks @Dhamotharan   The challenge here is that this would required the producer to publish to the different queues then and they are just a dumb client pushing every things it gets to the queue.  Making changes to it would complicate that logic and then making it decide which queue to publish to becomes hard.  

I like the idea though.  Will have to keep this in the back of my head for future work arounds.